# How to find all geographical places in a country in Freebase by using MQL Query?

Tags: freebase, mql

I would like to get all cities, regions, rivers, mountains, villages, areas from freebase by using MQL.

For now i only get all cities and district by using this query:

```
[{"type": "/location/location",
 "containedby": "Germany",
 "name": null}]
```

For now i do not understand how to get other geographical informations that are in germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found now this solution by executing 2 different queries, because i do not found how to do an UNION in mql:

```
[{
  "type": "/location/location",
  "partially_containedby": "Germany",
  "de:name": {
    "lang":  "/lang/de",
    "value": null
  },
 "geolocation": {
    "latitude":  null,
    "longitude": null
  }
}]
```

and

```
[{
  "type": "/location/location",
  "containedby": "Germany",
  "de:name": {
    "lang": "/lang/de",
    "value": null
  },
  "geolocation": {
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null
  }
}]
```

Both Queries retrieve me all location that are in germany or part of germany by returning the location's name in german, latitude and longitude.